# Form URL without id parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form:

```
form_for :comment, url: comment_path, method: :post do |f|
```

After rendering, this becomes

```
<form action="/comments/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

I would expect the `action` to be only `"/comments"` without the id, because that is the actual path for creating a new comment. And of course I get a nice error message saying that my path is invalid:

```
No route matches [POST] "/comments/1"
...
comments_path   GET     /comments(.:format)     comments#index
                POST    /comments(.:format)     comments#create
...
```

What am I doing wrong that puts that id into the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `comment_path` which is the show/edit/destroy route. Use `comments_path` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use *convention over configuration* instead:

```
# comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@comment) %>
<% end %>

# comments/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

When `@comment` is a new record it will use the path `comments_path` and for an existing record it will use `comment_path(@comment)` and set the method to PATCH. This lets you use the same form partial in different views.

You only really ever need to set the `path` and `method` options when you are doing something outside normal CRUD operations.